# Autocomplete `offset` optional parameter not working on Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm currently working with the `places` library of Google Maps API. I'm trying to switch from using `SearchBox` to using `Autocomplete` because I would like to make use of the `offset` optional parameter https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete in the following docs. Which in my understanding can only be done with `Autocomplete`. It is stated in above link:

> offset — The position, in the input term, of the last character that
>   the service uses to match predictions. For example, if the input is
>   'Google' and the offset is 3, the service will match on 'Goo'. The
>   string determined by the offset is matched against the first word in
>   the input term only. For example, if the input term is 'Google abc'
>   and the offset is 3, the service will attempt to match against 'Goo
>   abc'. If no offset is supplied, the service will use the whole term.
>   The offset should generally be set to the position of the text caret.

In order to reduce API calls, optional I set `offset` to 3. I instantiated the `Autocomplete` object the following way:

```
 this._autocomplete = new this._google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this._searchEl, {
      offset: 3,
      types: ['geocode'],
      bounds: this._map.getBounds(),
      strictBounds: true
    });
```

However, this didn't work. When inserting text into the input field I can see HTTP calls being made at the second key stroke. [image]

So I decided to check the docs and I found that `AutocompleteOptions` doesn't show the `offset` parameter:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-widget#AutocompleteOptions.fields

What is the proper way to pass `offset` to `Autocomplete` class of Google Places API?

Comment: There are options for the Autocomplete web service and options for the Autocomplete class. If some parameter is not specified in one of them, that means it doesn't exist. Full stop.

Comment: @MrUpsidown is there anything you suggest doing to accomplish something similar with the overall goal of decreasing API calls?

Comment: The AutocompleteService class can use [session tokens](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#session_tokens). That is not the default Autocomplete class. You need to retrieve predictions and build your own autocomplete widget. Simple example implementation (without sessions tokens) here: http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/dmwv1t4e/